# C# Use returned web service String as XML Data source in Grid View

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, gridview

I am not really an expert of .Net, I am trying to consume a Java webService which returns a XML code as a String (because it was easier for me to return a String rather than return an XML).

At the moment I am using an XML file (`test.xml`) in `App_Data` folder and my gridview works as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
            DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            Width="547px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/test.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

**What I have to do when I get the returned String from the Web Service?**

1) Should I **save the string as an XML**? In this case how can I save the String in the "`App_Data`" folder?

2) Is there **any other solution** instead of saving the String?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Data Property of your data source

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.data.aspx

I guess you will also need to remove the DataFile property set statically in you aspx file.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDataSource1.Data = ResultOfMyWebService;
}
```

Comment: mm I don't think I did it properly: <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" > <Data>String</Data> </asp:XmlDataSource>

Comment: [PersistenceModeAttribute(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        [TypeConverterAttribute("System.ComponentModel.MultilineStringConverter,System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")]
        public virtual string Data { get; set; }

Comment: Well... no. You have to do it in the code behind. Something like XmlDataSource1.Data = WebServiceResult. You could give the data in the constructor of the page and then set it in the Page_Load... depends on when your call to webservice is made